# Get rid of blogger image links

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, blogger

When you insert an image into a blogger post it shows up as a link. I know you can just edit the html and get rid of it but I dont want to do this for every image since I am posting at least once a day.

Is there a way to get rid image links in css? Then I could say for the post body section get rid of all image links.

Otherwise is there any other way that makes getting rid of the link faster?

Comment: by css you can hide those links but they will be there  in your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it with CSS. You could do it with script, but then everyone that viewed you blog would have to execute the script, all because you don't want to edit the HTML ;)

Are you using the new interface in Blogger? In the new version, blogger only seems to wrap images in a link if you position the image by dragging it. If you position it using align left or right (in the toolbar) the image is not wrapped in a link.

Really, I see no issue with manually removing the links in the HTML view. Are you really posting *that* many images that it takes too long to do this?!

Comment: Ok thanks. 
I am using the new interface. If I do what you said with the align left I cant seem to get the text to be in line with the top of the image but if I drag the image to the top left they line up.
The main reason I didnt want to edit the html was because someone else will have to do it and they dont know html so could easily screw it up :)

Comment: ahh no worries, can you provide detailed enough instructions that it won't be an issue? You could use CSS to line the text up with the top of the image, a little negative margin on p elements perhaps? I had a good look through the options for blogger and I couldn't see anything to actually disable the link-wrapping behaviour...You could make use of it though, are the images thumbnails? You could just lightbox them if so, then the link would actually be useful ;)

Comment: Sweet thanks. I just added float:left; to all images in the blog body and the text lines up no! :)